# Selecting elements of a list based on range

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

Suppose I have the following list:

```
  l={{{5}, {4, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 
   1, 1}}, {{6}, {5, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 1, 1}, {3, 3}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 1, 
   1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
   1}}}
```

I want to select those elements that have entries from 1 to 3, such that I get:

```
{{{3, 2}, {3, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}, {{3, 
   3}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 1, 
   1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}}
```

namely we dropped the elements that have integers beyond the range 1 to 3. I can not figure out how to use selection command in this case and wonder if selection is the best way at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When in doubt, one can always take the straightforward approach:

```
Select[VectorQ[#, IntegerQ[#] && Between[#, {1, 3}] &] &] /@ l
   {{{3, 2}, {3, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}},
    {{3, 3}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 1, 1},
     {2, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}}
```

Answer (score 11):

Tersely:

```
Cases[{(1|2|3)..}] /@ l
```

Answer (score 10):

Another possibility:

```
l /. a:{__Integer} /; Min[a]<1 || Max[a]>3 -> Nothing
```

> {{{3, 2}, {3, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}, {{3, 3}, {3, 
>      2, 1}, {3, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1,
>       1, 1}}}

Comment: The `Cases[]` variant: `Cases[a : {__Integer} /; 1 <= Min[a] && Max[a] <= 3] /@ l`.

Answer (score 10):

If you're interested in an idiomatic approach that uses curried operators:

```
Select[AllTrue[Between[{1, 3}]]] /@ l
```

**edit**

When there are only a few different integers you want to retain, the following is also an option:

```
Select[ContainsOnly[Range[1, 3]]] /@ l
```

Comment: Very nice. If you want to incorporate the check for integer entries: `Select[AllTrue[Through @* (IntegerQ && Between[{1, 3}])]] /@ l`.

Answer (score 8):

Another approach:

```
Pick[l, Map[ContainsOnly[#, Range[3]] &, l, {2}], True]
```

> {{{3, 2}, {3, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}, {{3, 
>      3}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 1, 
>      1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}}

Comment: The third argument of `Pick[]` is `True` by default, so `Pick[l, Map[ContainsOnly[#, Range[3]] &, l, {2}]]` suffices. A variation: `Pick[l, Map[Complement[#, {1, 2, 3}] === {} &, l, {2}]]`.

Answer (score 7):

```
Map[Select[FreeQ[0]]] @ Clip[l, {1, 3}, {0, 0}]
```

> {{{3, 2}, {3, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}},
>    {{3,  3}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}}}

Answer (score 6):

```
DeleteCases[l, {___, _?(!Between[#, {1, 3}] &), ___}, {2}]
```

> {{{3, 2}, {3, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}, {{3, 
>      3}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 1, 
>      1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}}

Comment: A slot-free variation: `DeleteCases[l, {___, _?(Not @* Between[{1, 3}]), ___}, {2}]`.

Answer (score 4):

my function:

```
Pick[l, And @@@ # & /@ Map[Abs[#] <= 3 &, l, {3}]]
```

Now since it has been a while since I used mathematica i decided to seize the opportunity and run some benchmarks so that I could refresh my memory while doing something fun. please if you have any advice or if you notice any error feel free to point them out.

For simplicity i have generated a 2 2-level list composed by 1000000 nested lists with variable lenght and different range of elements:

```
list = RandomInteger[{1, 5}, #] & /@ RandomInteger[{1, 5}, 1000000];
list2 =  RandomInteger[{1, 5}, #] & /@ RandomInteger[{1, 500}, 1000000];
```

then, starting from the solutions you guys provided, I defined some functions and each one of them has been given the name of the authors. I had to slightly modify them in order to make them work  with my sample list, I hope I didn't make a mess.
i will run the benchmark again if necessary.

```
jmfun[a_List] := Select[VectorQ[#, IntegerQ[#] && Between[#, {1, 3}] &] &]@a;
carlfun[b_List] := b /. a : {__Integer} /; Min[a] < 1 || Max[a] > 3 -> Nothing;
sjoerdfun[c_List] := Select[ContainsOnly[Range[1, 3]]]@c;
sjoerdfun2[c_List] := Select[AllTrue[Between[{1, 3}]]]@c;
jmxsjoerdfun[a_List] := Select[AllTrue[Through@*(IntegerQ && Between[{1,3}])]]@a;
wizarfun[a_List] := Cases[{(1 | 2 | 3) ..}]@a;
alxfun[c_List] := Pick[c, Map[ContainsOnly[#, Range[3]] &, c, {1}]];
jmxalxfun[c_List] := Pick[c, Map[Complement[#, {1, 2, 3}] === {} &, c]];
kglrfun[c_List] := Select[##, FreeQ[0]] &@Clip[c, {1, 3}, {0, 0}];
subafun[c_List] := DeleteCases[c, {___, _?(! Between[#, {1, 3}] &), ___}, {1}];
alucardfun[d_List] := Pick[d, And @@@ Map[ Abs[# ] <= 3 &, d, {2}]];
```

you may notice i didn't add wuyudi's answer  to the benchmark, the reason is that I don't understand anymore how it works and hence I could not define a working function with it.

the code i used for the benchmark:

```
authors = {  jmfun,   carlfun, sjoerdfun , sjoerdfun2 , jmxsjoerdfun, 
   wizarfun, alxfun, jmxalxfun, kglrfun, subafun, alucardfun};
results = {AbsoluteTiming[#[list]][[1]], #} & /@ authors // Sort;
results2 = {AbsoluteTiming[#[list2]][[1]], #} & /@ authors // Sort;
```

in the end the results were plotted on 2  different barchart plots.
 the first one has a linear scale:

```
Rasterize[
 Labeled[Framed[
   BarChart[results[[;; , 1]], ChartStyle -> "DarkRainbow", 
    AxesLabel -> Automatic, ChartLegends -> results[[;; , 2]], 
    ChartLabels -> 
     Placed[results[[;; , 2]], Above, Rotate[#, 67 Degree] &], 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick, Italic], 
    ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]], " test 1: Linear plot", Top, 
  LabelStyle -> 
   Directive[Bold, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 18]]]
```

[image]

the second one with a logarithmic scale:

```
Rasterize[
 Labeled[Framed[
   BarChart[results2[[;; , 1]], ChartStyle -> "DarkRainbow", 
    AxesLabel -> Automatic, ChartLegends -> results[[;; , 2]], 
    ChartLabels -> 
     Placed[results[[;; , 2]], Above, Rotate[#, 67 Degree] &], 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick, Italic], 
    ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]], " test 2: Log plot", Top, 
  LabelStyle -> 
   Directive[Bold, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 18]]]
```

which gives :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the benchmarking.  A few points: (1) In `alucardfun` you have the unbound Symbol `list` which I think is unintentional.  (2) I think you can use `results = {AbsoluteTiming[#[list]][[1]], #} & /@ authors // Sort` (3) Consider adding a second benchmark with longer sublists, e.g. `RandomInteger[{1, 500}, 100000]` and using `ScalingFunctions -> "Log"` in `BarChart`.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that list. thank you for your advices, I will fix everything this afternoon

Answer (score 3):

My way to do it

```
l // Select[1 <= #[[1]] <= 3 &] /@ # &
```

Comment: While your formula works with the supplied data, if you change the list l to include another element such as  {1,1,5}, it fails.  The general problem statement is that we should select any list with elements that are between 1 and 3 and you are only checking the first element for that condition.

Comment: @MarkR actually,you can use this to test `l={{{1}, {3, 4}}, {3}}`, the code given from others almost can't deal with it. That's the reason why this sort of list is unrecommended in mma.